# Remove Type from PHP Array: int(2) => "2"

Tags: php, date, datetime, epoch

I am attempting to store a Epoch timestamp as an integer in an a map in PHP, however, I am running into trouble getting the pure integer value, instead getting `(int)` before the value of the timestamp.

```
$property = "test property";
$date = new DateTime();
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
$tmpArray = array($property => $timestamp);
var_dump($tmpArray);
```

$tmpArray has a structure as the following:

> array(1) { ["test property"]=> int(1493778589) }

Is there a way to get the value in the map to be just `1493778047` without the `(int)` before it?

Comment: Please show the full relevant code.

Comment: What code are you using to display the contents of the array? I'm pretty sure that's where the `(int)` is coming from.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the full code that shows this. Can you replicate the issue that I am having?

Comment: The value is 1493778589. You use `var_dump`, it just tell you the type of the value in the map is integer.

Comment: Lol. I guess it's only easy when you know. But this made me laugh, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the output of `var_dump()`.

The value you have **IS** an integer. The `int()` you see it wrapped in is simply `var_dump()`'s way of telling you the data type.